# `DateTime.Parse` parses the timestamp in which timezone?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, parsing

I am parsing string time in date using `DateTime.Parse` method. It parses properly and returns me today's date with the entered time. But I am not able to determine the timezone when it takes the date part. Is it considering local date or UTC date?

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Your code goes here
        Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Parse("4:00"));
        //prints 09.05.2019 04:00:00 - here did it take 09.05.2019 from local timezone or is it UTC?
    }
}
```

On referring official [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parse?view=netframework-4.8) of `DateTime.Parse`, it is mentioned vaguely as follows:

> A string with a time but no date component. The method assumes the current date unless you call the Parse(String, IFormatProvider, DateTimeStyles) overload and include DateTimeStyles.NoCurrentDateDefault in the styles argument, in which case the method assumes a date of January 1, 0001.

I am confused what culture's exactly the date is being picked?

Comment: it will get timezone of executing machine

Comment: You can always check the source https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/datetime.cs,7f7fa04f5481a0ac (also `Parse` is not exactly the most straightforward code to look at, unlike most other methods)

Comment: It uses `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture` as reference. Change that with `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("fr-FR");` and it will show the Date/Time in French format. Specifying an `IFormatProvider` (in `DateTime.Parse("value", [IFormatProvider])`) won't change the result. The Time is the *number* you entered.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Neither, it is `Unspecified`.

First of all, in .NET Framework, [`DateTime` structure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime?view=netframework-4.8) does *not* keep timezone information. It has `Kind` property which reflects some information as `Utc`, `Local` or `Unspecified` but they are *not* perfectly refers a timezone.

In your case, since you don't supply any other parameters, your result `DateTime` will be `Unspecified`.

It is stated on the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parse?view=netframework-4.8#System_DateTime_Parse_System_String_) as;

> If `s` contains time zone information, this method returns a DateTime
>   value whose Kind property is `DateTimeKind.Local` and converts the date
>   and time in s to local time. **Otherwise, it performs no time zone
>   conversion and returns a DateTime value whose Kind property is
>   DateTimeKind.Unspecified.**

For representation part, when you use `DateTime` in `Console.WriteLine` method, it calls [`WriteLine(object)` overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.writeline?view=netframework-4.8#System_Console_WriteLine_System_Object_) and this [calls](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/textwriter.cs,499) the current `FormatProvider` which is [came from](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/textwriter.cs,119) `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am still confused. What if I want to show the date part of my local timezone? Shall I change CurrentCulture as mentioned in comment OR I need to change DateTime kind?

Comment: @KaranDesai I'm not sure what you mean by "show the date part of my local timezone" exactly. Do you wanna convert this `Unspecified` to `Local` as `Kind`? If so, you can just call the `ToLocalTime` method. Changing culture settings effects "how" your DateTime will be representation as _textual_ (aka string).

Answer (score 0):

By Default, it picks the system's currently active culture (on which the C# Code is being executed) local date and its format and then appends your time to that date. As your time has only single numeric value i.e 4 so it'll list it as 4 AM.

So output can be like `09.05.2019 04:00:00` or `5/9/2019 4:00:00 AM` depending upon the server's system current format on which the code is executed. You can see the system's current culture by right-clicking on time in Windows Taskbar and see the format.